# How to call cordova plugin action synchronously in Button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

How to call cordova plugin action synchronously in Button click in java script

We need to upgrade every javascript annotation method to plugin format with synchronously.

Java - Our own plugin

```
public class ProjectUtility extends CordovaPlugin{
    public static final String TAG = " Project Utility";
    private final static String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
    DataMgnt dm = new DataMgnt();
    public CordovaInterface cordovaInterface; 
    public ProjectUtility() {
        System.out.println(" project utility");
    }

    /**
    * Sets the context of the Command. This can then be used to do things like
    * get file paths associated with the Activity.
    *
    * @param cordova The context of the main Activity.
    * @param webView The CordovaWebView Cordova is running in.
    */

    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    cordovaInterface=cordova;
    Log.v(TAG,"Init CoolPlugin dsfsdf" +cordova.getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name));
    }

    public boolean execute(final String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    final int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;



    // Shows a toast
    Log.v(TAG,"CoolPlugin received: dsfsdfdssdadfa"+ action);


    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), cordovaInterface.getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name), duration);
    toast.show();
    if(action.equals("imei"))
    {
        callbackContext.success(getImeiNumber());
    }
    else if(action.equals("app_name")){
        callbackContext.success(appName());
    }
    else if(action.equals("service_id")){ 
        callbackContext.success(getServiceId());
    }
    else
    {
        callbackContext.error("fail");
    }
    }
    });

    return true;
    }

    public String getImeiNumber()
    {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) cordovaInterface.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imeiId="";
        try{
            imeiId = tm.getDeviceId();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              imeiId="null";
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return "12364589785451";
    }
     String getServiceId()
     {
         String service_id= cordovaInterface.getActivity().getString(R.string.service_id);
         return service_id;
     }
    public String appName()
    {
        return cordovaInterface.getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name);
    }

    }
```

**javascript :
utlity.js**
  We initialize common funtion to access the plugin:

```
window.sdpproperty = function(key,arg_array ,callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
        callback('error');
    }, "ProjectUtility", key,arg_array);    


};
```

**index.html** – we accessing window.property function,

This file contain two functions,
1) we_need_like_this()
2) but_it_work_like_this_no_need_this_format()
3) sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script>
            function we_need_like_this() {
                var service_id,
                imei;
                window.sdpproperty("service_id", [], function (echoValue) {
                    service_id = echoValue;
                    alert("Inside Inside the call back exec the service id    " + echoValue)
                });
                window.sdpproperty("imei", [], function (echoValue) {
                    imei = echoValue;
                    alert("Inside  call back exec the imei    " + echoValue)
                });
                sample(service_id, imei)
            }

            function sample(service_id, imei) {
                alert("Inside the Sample func. Service Id   " + service_id + " Imei   " + imei);
            }

            function but_it_work_like_this_no_need_this_format() {
                var service_id,
                imei;
                window.sdpproperty("service_id", [], function (echoValue) {
                    service_id = echoValue;
                    window.sdpproperty("imei", [], function (echoValue) {
                        imei = echoValue;
                        sample(service_id, imei)
                    });
                });
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">            
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">..... App Loading....</p>             
            </div>
           <button onclick="we_need_like_this()">We Need</button> 
            <button onclick="but_it_work_like_this_no_need_this_format()">We no Need</button> 
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utlity.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which cordova plugin are you using?

Comment: cordova version 5.1.0

Comment: No, which [plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) are you using in your Cordova app?

Comment: Our own plugin and js file is updated @beaver

Comment: I updated my Question @beaver

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you wish to achieve. Please be more clear, I have little time...

Comment: My problem is , still now we are using cordova 2.9.0 version , now onwards we are moving to upgrade our cordova latest version, We have used every native function using "@JavascriptInterface" annotation , it returns value from javascript. But we are unable to use "@javascriptInterface" annotation functionality in latest version of cordova.

We need some return value from native function, but we are unable to get the value returned by plugin functionality and we need synchronous actions but plugins are run asynchronously .

We are using cordova version :5.0.1 @beaver

Answer (score 0):

As of [Cordova Plugins dev docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html#the-javascript-interface) the JS interface must have:

```
cordova.exec(function(winParam) {},
    function(error) {},
    "service",
    "action",
    ["firstArgument", "secondArgument", 42, false]);
```

and your definition has:

```
cordova.exec(callback, 
    function(err) { callback('error');  }, 
    "ProjectUtility", 
    key,
    arg_array);
```

so the parameter `key` is the action to be executed on the native side.

Examining your JAVA file the actions available are these:

- authencation_hash_encrypt  **<---- PAY ATTENTION THERE IS A TYPO!**
- service_id
- authencation_encrypt  **<---- PAY ATTENTION THERE IS A TYPO!**
- authentication_hash_decrypt
- decrypt_value
- decrypt
- authent_token
- new_decrypt
- authencation_hash_encrypt  **<---- PAY ATTENTION THERE IS A TYPO!**
- encrypt_value
- encrypt_hash

So the value "key_cre" as key parameter is not present...